# Ext js 6.2 CORS not working for a store declared in viewModel

Tags: javascript, extjs, cors, store, extjs6

I have the following store defined in store:

```
Ext.define('EDUX.store.Students', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.students',
    fields: ['fname', 'lname', 'age', 'enrol', 'class','gender'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'get',
        withCredentials: true,
        url: global.getBaseUrl() + 'api/api.php?student=view',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'rows'
        }
    }
});
```

CORS works as expected. However, when I define the same store in viewModel, CORS does not work. Following is my code in viewModel:

```
Ext.define('EDUX.view.settings.SettingsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.settings',
    data: {
        name: 'EDUX',
        school: 'Programme'
    },
    stores: {
        students: {
            fields: ['fname', 'lname', 'age', 'enrol', 'class','gender'], withCredentials: true,
            proxy: {url:global.getBaseUrl() + 'api/api.php?student=view',type: 'ajax', reader: {type: 'json', rootProperty: 'rows'}},
autoLoad:true
        }}
});
```

Is there something am missing or could it be a bug?

Comment: When CORS blocks requests, you get an error message as to why it fails. Since we don't see what you're doing on the server side, we have to guess unless you can provide an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your store definitions are not the same, which you would clearly see if you would use proper indentation. Your standalone definition:

```
fields: ['fname', 'lname', 'age', 'enrol', 'class','gender'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'get',
    withCredentials: true,
    url: global.getBaseUrl() + 'api/api.php?student=view',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'rows'
    }
}
```

Your viewmodel definition, prettified:

```
fields: ['fname', 'lname', 'age', 'enrol', 'class','gender'], 
withCredentials: true,
proxy: {
    url:global.getBaseUrl() + 'api/api.php?student=view',
    type: 'ajax', 
    reader: {
        type: 'json', 
        rootProperty: 'rows'
    }
},
autoLoad:true
```

You should definitely check whether `withCredentials` can be defined on both store or proxy, or whether this causes the difference; whether `autoLoad` changes anything, whether `method:'get'` changes anything.

Comment: Hi, you are right. Moving withCredentials: true inside the proxy solved the problem. Thank you all for the feedback.